# How to send buffer data from client to server 4 characters at a time? (C++)

Tags: c++, networking, udp

I am trying to build a UDP file transfer system with C++ that will allow the client to send four characters of a text file to the server at a time. The server will then take the four characters and add them to a new file on the server. I am confused on how to actually implement this. I know that a loop of some kind will have to be created on the client and server to continuously send data from the client and receive data on the server I just don't know how to implement it. I will post the code that I have so far for the client and server below. Any help is appreciated!

**Client Code**

```
// *** Declare UDP socket ***
int udpsocket = 0;
udpsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (udpsocket == -1) {
    cerr << "Can't create a socket";
    return 1;
}

// Get host IP address
s = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

// Setting destination info
memset((char *) &server, 0, sizeof(server));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(r_port);
bcopy((char *) s->h_addr, (char *) &server.sin_addr.s_addr, s->h_length);

// File manipulation
fp = fopen(file.c_str(), "r");
    while (c != EOF) {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        fileString += c;
        charCounter++;
    }
fclose(fp);

// UDP file transfer  
socklen_t slen = sizeof(server);
memset(payload, 0, sizeof(payload));
strcpy(payload, dataBuffer.c_str());

sendRes = sendto(udpsocket, payload, 512, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server, slen);
if (sendRes == -1) {
    cerr << "Could not send to server";
    return 1;
}
close(udpsocket);
return 0;
```

**Server Code**

```
// *** Declare UDP socket ***
    int udpsocket = 0;
    udpsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (udpsocket == -1) {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket";
        return -1;
    }

    // Receive data
    memset((char *) &server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(r_port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(udpsocket, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) == -1) {
        cerr << "Can't bind to IP/Port";
        return -2;
    }

    clen = sizeof(client);
    memset(payload, 0, sizeof(payload));
    recvfrom(udpsocket, payload, 512, 0, (sockaddr*)&client, &clen);
    cout << "Payload: " << payload << "\n";

    close(udpsocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First things to do are read up on loops and remember that if you want to send 4 bytes, telling `sendto` to send 512 bytes is a non-starter.

Comment: I think sockets always transfer some number of bytes ... so what are you expecting a pack-4-bytes to do for you?  And if your msg is not a multiple of 4 bytes, will you 'fill' or not?  I vaguely remember that the smallest packet that can be sent is 64? bytes.  And the upper limit for MTU is most likely 1500 bytes.  So, why pack-by-4?  Read up on sockets ... good luck.

Comment: "*I am trying to build a UDP file transfer system with C++ that will allow the client to send four characters of a text file to the server at a time.*" - why only 4 chars at a time?  Why not use an actual UDP-based file transfer protocol, like [TFTP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1350)?